# AWS SQS API: List non empty queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am reading this documentation about [Amazon AWS SQS API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ListQueues.html). The documentation explain it is possible to list all my queues. However I was wondering whether there is a way to list all my queues which are not empty. Is it possible?

My current approach is to get all my queues and then I have to filter them by size. However it implies to perform many requests to the API. I would be pleased to remove those request from my app side.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can filter by queues that are not empty

Your current approach of calling "ListQueues" and then "GetQueueAttributes" for each one is probably the best way to do it

Comment: I think this is correct.  Also worth noting, `GetQueueAttributes` is sort of eventually consistent, returning only an [approximate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-resources-required-process-messages.html) (not necessarily authoritative) number of messages visible.